# Assertion not valid in script though type comparison works in terminal

Tags: python, assertions

I encounter a quite strange issue with comparison.

I want to decode python script arguments, store them and analyse them. In the following command, the -r option shall be used to determine which type of report to create.

python script launching :
`%run decodage_parametres_script.py -r junit,html`

python script options parsing is used to fill a dictionary, the result is:
current_options :

`{'-cli-no-summary': False, '-cli-silent': False, '-r': ['junit', 'html']}`

Then I want to test the -r options, here is the code:

```
for i in current_options['-r']:
    # for each reporter required with the -r option:
    #    - check that a file path has been configured (otherwise set default)
    #    - create the file and initialize fields
    print("trace i", i)
    print("trace current_options['-r'] = ", current_options['-r'])
    print("trace current_options['-r'][0] = ", current_options['-r'][0])

    if current_options['-r'][i] == 'junit':
        # request for a xml report file
        print("request xml export")
        try:
            xml_file_path = current_option['--reporter-junit-export']
            print("xml file path = ", xml_file_path)
        except:
            # missing file configuration
            print("xml option - missing file path information")
            timestamp = get_timestamp()
            xml_file_path = 'default_report' + '_' + timestamp + '.xml'
            print("xml file path = ", xml_file_path)
        if xml_file_path is not None:
            touch(xml_file_path)
            print("xml file path = ", xml_file_path)
        else:
            print('ERROR: Empty --reporter-junit-export path')
            sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("no xml file required")
```

I want to try the default report generation but I don't even hit the print("request xml export") line, here is the console result :

```
trace i junit
trace current_options['-r'] =  ['junit', 'html']
trace current_options['-r'][0] =  junit
```

As I guess it could be a type issue, I tried the following tests:

```
In [557]: for i in current_options['-r']:
 ...:     print(i, type(i))
 ...:
junit <class 'str'>
html <class 'str'>

In [558]: toto = 'junit'

In [559]: type(toto)
Out[559]: str

In [560]: toto
Out[560]: 'junit'

In [561]: toto == current_options['-r'][0]
Out[561]: True
```

so my line assertion `if current_options['-r'][i] == 'junit'`: should end up begin True but it's not the case.
Am I missing something trivial ???  :(

Can someone help me, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating by array of strings

```
for i in current_options['-r']:
```

in your case `i` will be:
 `junit` on first iteration
 `html`  on next iteration

and your if condition (from interpreter perspective) will looks like:

```
  if current_options['-r']['junit'] == 'junit':
```

instead of expected:

```
  if current_options['-r'][0] == 'junit':
```

**Solution 1:**
You need iterate through of `range(len(current_options['-r']))`

**Solution 2**
change your comparator:
from

```
if current_options['-r'][i] == 'junit':
```

to

```
if i == 'junit':
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works  :)  I didn't see it despite my prints. I'll use solution 1  ;)